# jquery id selector with strange symbols \\

Tags: jquery, selector

Who knows what this symbols `\\` do in jquery selector ? 
Thank You!

Full code:

```
$("#solr\\.queryInput").attr("value", "");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes.

---

In your case there must be any div/span with id solr.queryInput ( `id="solr.queryInput"`)

**Example**

If `id="foo.bar"` ,then you should use `$("#foo\\.bar")` not `$("#foo.bar")`

```js
$("#foo.bar").css({"background":"red"});

$("#foo1\\.bar1").css({"background":"red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo.bar">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="foo1.bar1">
Hello World 1
</div>
```